# When calculating moon phases and prayer times found acceptance among the scholars?

Tags: history, fiqh, science, lunar-calendar

After posting the question [Are questions on the historical inauguration of some "utilities" or "methods" on topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/are-questions-on-the-historical-inauguration-of-some-utilities-or-methods-on) on meta I finally decided to ask ask it here:

I'm pretty sure that calendars or methods to calculate the moon phases have been developed in the golden ages of islamic caliphates, as there have been lots of scientists such al-Biruni (even Imam Malik has been said to have written a book about that) and many others. But what I'd like to know is:

When and where scholars or clerics introduced or accepted them as a utility for declaring or calculating important dates like 1st day of Ramadan?

Any details on this historical inauguration would be fine!

I think of information like: how was the general acceptance at the time, who was the cleric, who was the person or scientists whom's caclulation methods or calendar was accepted ...

Answer (score -1):

i have found some information in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Islamic_calendar :

> The Tabular Islamic calendar (an example is the Fatimid or Misri
>   calendar) is a rule-based variation of the Islamic calendar. It has
>   the same numbering of years and months, but the months are determined
>   by arithmetical rules rather than by observation or astronomical
>   calculations. It was developed by early Muslim astronomers of the
>   second hijra century (the 8th century of the Common Era) to provide a
>   predictable time base for calculating the positions of the moon, sun,
>   and planets. ...

but i do not know anything other than that.

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate an answer, I'm afraid sooner or later this would be considered a link-only answer and deleted. It also would be great to know when sunni people started to "trust" a calculated calendar!

Answer (score -2):

it is quite hard and as i know a good algorithm was invented only in 20th century: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/islam_lunvis.htm . and it seems to me it is not very good, because it is written there that new moon visible only after sunset, but i saw in stellarium that it is visible before sunrise in southern hemisphere.

and it is not muslim scientist invented that, as i see.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question at least not what I'm interessted in.

Comment: @Medi1Saif i guess http://islamicfinder.org/islamic-calendar/ etc use that algorithm to calculate first days of months. if i proved that, would my answer be ok?

Comment: My request is more about history than about technical details!

Comment: @Medi1Saif why you are sure that they calculated that in golden ages? they probably just watched that.

Comment: I'm sure of nothing, but since I left my homeland I noticed that many Muslim countries relay on calculated calendars, so I'd like to know when this view of allowing calculation or basing a calendar on calculcation started or was adapted! I'm not interested in how to calculate.