# Consistent calendar by sight

Tags: lunar-calendar, moon

What if at any 29th day of the month, the weather is always bad, so you can't observe anything, so that you always need to add a 30th day to the month

And what if at the contrary, you can always observe the moon at the 29th day and all your months are only 29 days

I think the second case can not be possible as the moon doesn't do a cycle every 29 day but 29,5 days, so you should be able to keep a good pace with the observation

But in the first case, their calendar will be late, their year will last longer

So is there any other system (than observing at the 29th day) to correct a bad weather in order to correct the calendar, to synchronize a way or another?

It's already difficult some months where all countries have difficulties not to be synchronized (in the same country people fight each-other to know when begin ramadhan), but over a year, it's impossible (12 day difference per year maximum, so a completely different calendar depending on the country)

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information on our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. The calendar is consistent Muslims are not as half of the Muslim countries follow Saudi Arabia's wrong Umm al-Qura calendar and the majority of the remaining the faulty Turkish calculation. And a handful: namely Morocco, Iran, Oman and some more the local sighting.

Comment: You didn't replied the question at all, how in the first case the community can correct themselves?

Comment: Some related posts: [Why astronomical calculations supercede non-sighting of the moon in some islamic communities](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48724/why-astronomical-calculations-supercede-non-sighting-of-the-moon-in-some-islamic?rq=1) and [What are the opinions on moonsighting as per classical scholars?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35556/what-are-the-opinions-on-moonsigthing-as-per-the-classical-scholars?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Still not the question...

Comment: But the answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: What i've understood from your link is that for some scholars, calculations can help when the weather is bad, and for some other nothing can help a bad weather